# how to export nested dict into excel file?

Tags: python, excel, csv, dictionary, xlsx

my dict:

```
myDict = {0: {'max': 30,
              'min': 10},
          1: {'max': 40,
              'min': 25}
          }
```

How can I get this into an excel file looking like this:

```
        0        1
max    30       40
min    10       25
```

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(myDict).to_excel("file.xlsx")`?

Comment: in `pd ` do you mean `pandas`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pandas.to_excel()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html):

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(myDict).to_excel("file.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need fancy formatting for your file, you can create a csv file (which can be opened in applications other than Microsoft Excel)

`pandas` can do the job:

```
import pandas
csv_str = pandas.DataFrame(myDict).to_csv()
print(csv_str)
```

You can write the string to a file, or give a file path parameter to `to_csv`:

```
csv_str = pandas.DataFrame(myDict).to_csv('file.csv')
```